# Filebeat not logging to files, always only to syslog

Tags: filebeat

My filebeat (v7.6.0) config has the following:

```
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0755
```

It doesn't create the files, nor does it log to them, it just continues to log to syslog instead.

What haven't I done/have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

```
When Filebeat is running on a Linux system with systemd, it uses by default the -e command line option, that makes it write all the logging output to stderr so it can be captured by journald. Other outputs are disabled.
```

Comment: Maybe this is missing?
`logging.to_syslog: false`